# Can't include ngMessages Module in Angularjs application after bower install

Tags: angularjs, bower, angularjs-module

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to install and import the angular-messages module in an angularjs project.  Here is the error message

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMessages due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngMessages' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/nomod?p0=ngMessages
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:66:12
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2262:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2183:38)
    at module
```

As you can see from below, I believe that I've imported the angular messages module properly (in index.html).

I've also included images of the file paths and of my app.js that does the import of ngMessage.  Bower versions seem to be ok as well.  Any thoughts?

[image]

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Post your code as text, not as images. And use the same version number for all angular dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version of `ng-messages` is not compatible with the version of AngularJS. Try strict versions in your dependency configuration:

```
{
  "name": "angular-seed",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.6.0",
    "angular-route": "1.6.0",
    "angular-loader": "1.6.0",
    "angular-mocks": "1.6.0",
    "angular-messages": "1.6.0"
  }
}
```